# Laravel eloquent returns null on eager loading nested relation but lazy loading works

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a query with some nested relations but I can't get it to work. Trying to eager load things gives me a 'null' but when I lazy load everything works.

I also noticed that eager load works if I just get 10 rows or so.

Scenario is like this: I have 4 Models, let's call them MainModel, NestedModel, DeepNestedModel and AbyssModel;

MainModel is as follows:

```php
public function nested() {
    return $this->hasMany(NestedModel::class, 'nested_id', 'id');
}
```

NestedModule is like this:

```php
public function deep_nested() {
    return $this->belongsTo(DeepNestedModel::class, 'deep_nested_id', 'id');
}
```

And DeepNestedModule is like this:

```php
public function abyss() {
    return $this->belongsTo(DeepNested::class, 'abyss_id', 'id');
}
```

Now I need to get to AbyssModel from MainModel.

What I've tried:

```php
//first try
$m = new MainModel();
$collection = $m->with('nested.deep_nested.abyss')->get();
$collection[0]->nested[0]->deep_nested; //this gives me a null, so i can't get to the abyss

//second limiting the query
$m = new MainModel();
$collection = $m->with('nested.deep_nested.abyss')->take(10)->get();
$collection[0]->nested[0]->deep_nested; //this works and I can get to the abyss, but if I change the code to take 11, then it gives me null again

//third no limits but with lazy loading
$m = new MainModel();
$collection = $m->with('nested')->get();
foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
    $value->nested[0]->deep_nested; //works and I can get to the abyss
}

//wanted behavior is
$m = new MainModel();
$collection = $m->with('nested.deep_nested.abyss')->get();
foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
    //do my stuff with MainModel, NestedModel, DeepNestedModel and the Abyss
}
```

I have no clue why is this happening.

I wanted to eager load this to avoid a bunch of extra queries. I'll definitely limit the query but 10 is not acceptable. So, why this is not working? Is there something wrong with the relations on my models?

Comment: Have you checked if it's bad data and it is not provided how you create these nestings.

Comment: the data is ok since I can get to it by querying one by one or by limiting results. What do you mean by 'not provided how you create these nestings'? I use the attach/detach methods, it this what you mean?